# How to write mathematical formula describing my lmer model?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, notation

I have the following model fitted using the `lme4` package in R:

```
mod <- lmer(var1 ~ var2 * var3 + (1|var4) , data=s1, REML=F)
```

I want to express this as an equation. I have the following:

$$
Y_{i} = 
\beta_0 + 
\beta_{0\varpi} + 
\beta_{1\nu}\nu_i + 
\beta_{1\varsigma}\varsigma_i + 
\beta_{1\vartheta}\nu_i\varsigma_i +
e_{i} 
$$

Where $\nu=var2$, $\varsigma=var3$ and $\varpi = var4$, so $\beta_0$ is the overall intercept, $\beta_{0\varpi}$ is the random intercept for var4, $\beta_{1\nu}\nu_i$ is the slope for var2, $\beta_{1\varsigma}\varsigma_i$ is the slope for var3 and $\beta_{1\vartheta}\nu_i\varsigma_i$ is the slope for the interaction (var2,var3).

I am wondering if this is the best way to express this model/if there are any better alternatives (such as expressing var2 and var3 as a matrix)?

Comment: It's conventional to use Latin letters for variables and Greek for coefficients. I would write: \begin{gather}
y\sim\mathcal N(\beta_0 + \beta_1\cdot x + \beta_2\cdot y + \beta_3\cdot xy, \sigma^2_e) \\
\beta_0 \sim \mathcal N(\bar\beta_0, \sigma^2_0)
\end{gather}With a slight abuse of notation one can also write it a bit simpler as \begin{gather}
y = \beta_0 + \beta_1\cdot x + \beta_2\cdot y + \beta_3\cdot xy\\
\beta_0 \sim \mathcal N(\bar\beta_0, \sigma^2_0)
\end{gather}

Comment: @amoeba, post as answer? You can express this in matrix notation ($\mathbf y = \mathbf X \mathbf \beta + \mathbf Z \mathbf b$ etc.) but I think amoeba's notation is probably clearer.  Depends on your audience.

Comment: @amoeba, thanks for that, just 2 questions: 1) you use $y$ twice - for a fixed effect variable and the dependent variable...is this not a bit confusing, or am I missing something?  2) where is the random intercept in your equation?

Comment: @BenBolker, is the matrix notation was more widely used? It seems to be in text books. But thinking about it, my audience will probably be better off with the long hand form

Comment: (1) You are right, this should be changed. Do your variables `var1`, `var2`, etc. have some meaningful names? If so, I would write smth like $$\mathrm{Height}=\beta_0+\beta_1\cdot\mathrm{Age}+\beta_2...$$ As long as you have only a handful of variables this is going to be fine. (2) $\beta_0$ is the intercept and the second line shows that it's random. $\bar\beta_0$ is the "fixed intercept" and $\sigma^2_0$ is the variance of random intercept.

Comment: By the way, this assumes that your `var2` and `var3` are continuous. If they are categorical, then the model has to be written differently.

Comment: @amoeba, great, thank you. But yes, they are not all continuous. var1 and var2 are continuous, var3 and var4 are categorical. So I shouldn't express them as normally distributed. To give them more meaningful names: $Rating = \beta_0 + \beta_{0Subject} + \beta_1 \cdot Distance + \beta_2 \cdot Item + \beta_3 \cdot Item \cdot Distance + e$ Where $Subject$ is random categorical, $Distance$ is fixed continuous, $Item$ is fixed categorical

Comment: Well, this information is crucial. If `Item` is categorical then it does not make any sense to write $\beta_2\cdot\mathrm{Item}$... The value of `Item` is an integer, but we are not multiplying beta with this integer. Instead, one can write $\gamma_i$ where $i$ can take values from 1 to K-1 where K is the number of levels of the `Item` factor. You are essentially fitting different intercepts for different values of Item. And similarly for the interaction term.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused now! I have seen this notation used for categorical variables in a couple of places (equation 1 on page 9 of [this doc] (http://talklab.psy.gla.ac.uk/KeepItMaximalR2.pdf) and in [this course video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BDA5b-gtbc) (from around 1m in). I feel that I'm missing something obvious here? Just to clarify, are you saying the equation would be:

Comment: (cont.) $Rating = \beta_0 + \beta_{0Subject} + \beta_1 \cdot Distance + \gamma_i + \beta_3 \cdot Distance \cdot \gamma_i + \epsilon $? That doesn't look right to me either. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: @tribalsoul (Please ping me with `@amoeba` when you reply.) Eq 1 on page 9 in Barr et al. considers X that is indeed categorical but has only 2 levels. That's a bit of a special case, because then there is only one additional intercept to be estimated, so one can write $\beta\cdot X$ as they do. Is your `Item` also binary or does it have more levels?

Comment: @amoeba, sorry, I realise that this would have been much more efficient had I included all the pertinent information at the outset. $Item$ has 30 levels (and $Subject$ has ~50 levels). I now see why $\beta_2 \cdot Item$ would only apply for 2 levels (one being the base (in r), and the coefficient being the difference from base, for the second level. I have 30 coefficients for $Item$, and 30 for the interaction $Item * Distance$. I am starting to think matrix notation may be the best way to express this, although I prefer the long form, if it doesn't mean listing out all the coefficients.

Comment: [cont.] Could the $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ set of coefficients not be expressed as vectors?

Comment: So if `Item` is categorical then instead of $\beta \cdot \mathrm{Item}$ you can write something like $\gamma_k$ and explain that $k$ stands for Item number $k$, or you can write the same thing more explicitly as $\gamma_k \cdot I(\mathrm{Item}=k)$. Here $I()$ is an indicator function. By the way, note that 30 levels is quite a lot, so you should consider making `Item` a random effect.

Comment: (I am considering to write a proper answer to this question but if so I'd like it to be comprehensive and as you can see this gets quite involved...)

Comment: @amoeba, great, thanks. That makes sense. I'm aware 30 levels is a lot, but the main thing I am interested in is the 30 coefficients for the interaction (I want to evaluate how good a predictor $Distance$ is at each level of $Item$. I calculate the CIs for each of the interaction coefficients, and am interested in cases of $Item$ where the CIs do not cross 0 (i.e. sig neg/pos slopes). The model does not seem deficient doing this. I appreciate your input and would happily upvote an answer. I think it would be useful to others also.

Comment: I have similar question here, could someone help to answer this? Thanks a lot.