# Formular of my lmer() Model

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, lme4-nlme

I know there is already a lot of information out there, e.g. [How to write mathematical formula describing my lmer model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/308581/how-to-write-mathematical-formula-describing-my-lmer-model/580822#580822).

I have Data from Soil C/N ratios relatet to tree species(PFT), Slope (HNnum) from different Plots and Elevation levels.  I applied following linear mixed Models to identify significant effects on C/N ratio.

My `lmer()` Model is pretty similar, but with two random factors, therfore im not shure about my formular. Whereas I have read that two-component random effekts are estimated in a Matrix?

`lmer(CNratio ~ HNnum + PFT + (1 | plot) + (1 | Elevation), data = Data)`

would be:

[image]

Huge thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm quite sure we need to know what you want to measure / describe. Could you please explain your experiment/analysis?

Comment: Hey Ben, I have Data from Soil C/N ratios relatet to Plant species(PFT), Slope (HNnum) from different Plots and Elevation levels. With this Model I want to test what influence/relation Vegetation and slope is having on the Nitrogen concentration in the Soil.

Comment: I would say yes but I'm not an expert. Also have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet